# Why is my Form not Closing/Hiding?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I don't get it why my Log in form is not closing or hiding even though I am already using the "this.Hide, I am trying to close the from then opening another one, the second form is opening but the Log in is still there running why is that?
here is my code

```
public void verifyAccount()
        {
            var hashedPassword = getPassword();

            var hasher = new Hasher();

            hasher.SaltSize = 16;

             hasher.CompareStringToHash(txtPassword.Text, hashedPassword);

            if (!hasher.CompareStringToHash(txtPassword.Text, hashedPassword))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName or Password");
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

                main.ShowDialog();
                this.Hide();
            }   
        }
```

EDIT:  With the peoples comment I found an Idea of how will I close the log in form, here's my workaround

```
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                this.Hide();
                main.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main.ShowDialog();` is a blocking call. Control will not run to the next line until you close  the main window.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you using `ShowDialog` which wait for the form to be closed before executing anymore code. Try

```
main.Show();
this.Close();
```

Comment: But after that my second from is also Closing

Answer (score 0):

ShowDialog shows the form as a modal dialog box, so it's blocking the call to this.Hide().  Hide() will only get called after you close MainWindow.  You have a couple options: call this.Hide() before ShowDialog.  Or don't have your MainWindow be modal.

Answer (score 0):

Your login form is the parent of the main application in this case. From an application design point of view it might be better if:

1. Program.cs opens the login form modally
2. User enters credentials and presses login
3. Credentials are checked and if correct form closes, execution is returned to program.cs
4. Program.cs checks a property on the form to determine whether login was successful
5. If so, the main application form is opened

Please note however that this doesn't truly make the app secure as someone could reference your exe in their own project and programmatically open your main form.  But that's another discussion.