# Can't hide or close form after switching to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to switch Windows forms after successful login at the login form, I move to the main form. The problem is once the user logs in by clicking the login button, the main form opens **but the login forms stays in the background, won't go away**. I tried this.hide() and this.close, but they don't work. Here's some of the code from the btnLogin event...

```
        //connection to access database and checking if the user exist, ...
        ...
        if (!rdr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password.");

        }
        else 
            GlobalClass.GlobalVar = true;
            GlobalClass.GlobalStr = rdr["user"].ToString();
            MainScreen _main = new MainScreen();
            _main.ShowDialog();

        rdr.Close();
        conn.Close();
        this.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use Show instead of ShowDIalog

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442435/why-is-it-that-my-form-is-not-closing-hiding?rq=1

Comment: You were right about using Show() instead of ShowDialog(). I also put the Show() and this.Close in brackets because it was giving me "InvalidOperationException No data exists for the row/column" error... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `ShowDialog` use `Show` method instead, here:

```
_main.Show();
```

When you use `ShowDialog` your program waits until you close your `MainForm` and doesn't go to the next line.So your second form doesn't close until you close the `MainForm`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to create and display the main form from Program.cs, and then show and dispose the LoginDialog from the OnLoad handler of the main form.

In particular if LoginDialog is created from Application.Run then closing it will exit the app, so not very useful that way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can `hide()` then `close()` but you have to use an event in doing so and like others suggest I will use `Show()` method instead of `ShowDialog()`.

I would probably declare globally the Main form first.

```
MainScreen _main;
```

Then when you are about to show the Main after login use event to `Hide()` the login Form and then an event to `Close()` login form once Main form is closed.

```
GlobalClass.GlobalVar = true;
GlobalClass.GlobalStr = rdr["user"].ToString();
_main = new MainScreen();
_main.Load += new EventHanlder(_main_Load);
_main.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(_main_FormClosed);
_main.Show();
```

Catch the event for `Main` **Form loading** to `Hide` the Login form, like:

```
private void _main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide(); // Hides Login but it is till in Memory
}
```

Catch the event for `Main` **Form closing** to `Close` the Login form, like:

```
private void _main_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close(); // Closes Login and remove this time from Memory
}
```